# Using global from different modules

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a modular project, where the main module (entrypoint) is written in javascript, meanwhile some auxiliary libs are in typescript.
The javascript module, when starts, assign some set of variables, using `global`.
The problem is I don't to share this variables with the typescript libs.
It runs, but I'm getting some error when publishing:
`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.`

The javascript set these variables as below:

```
static loadProperties() {
    global.myProperties = new Map();
    global.myProperties.set('SOME_VARIABLE', 'someValue');
}
```

The typescript lib uses it as following:

```
const someVariable: string = global.myProperties.get('SOME_VARIABLE');
```

But when running the `npm run compile` command, throws the exception mentioned before.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to be told to avoid global variables?

Comment: @Bergi I want to fix the error

Comment: Well either add a `declare global` for the variable or just suppress the error. Or don't use global variables in the first place and properly import it from a (typed) module or pass it as a configuration parameter to the typescript library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you global really don't have any such attribute

I really don't recommend using `global.` but if you want to, here's how:

`global.d.ts`:

```js
declare namespace NodeJS {
  export interface Global {
    myProperties: Map<unknown, unknown>
  }
}

// and / or top-level module
declare var myProperties: Map<unknown, unknown>
```

In addition, your code has a syntax error:

```js
static loadProperties() {
    global.myProperties = new Map();
    // global.myProperties.set('SOME_VARIABLE') = 'someValue';
    global.myProperties.set('SOME_VARIABLE', 'someValue');
}
```